# Cucumber: How to specify 2 feature files to run in Intellij vm "Run Configuration"?

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber

I have multiple feature files in my project and I would like, for example run only 2 of them.

To run one of them I write in the vm line inside the IntelliJ's "Run Configuration" dialog box:

```
-Dcucumber.options="--tags @FirstFeature"
```

and it runs it as expected.

But for two features files I tried all the following with no success:

```
-Dcucumber.options="--tags @FirstFeature --tags @SecondFeature"
-Dcucumber.options="--tags @FirstFeature @SecondFeature"
-Dcucumber.options="--tags @FirstFeature and @SecondFeature"
-Dcucumber.options="--tags @FirstFeature, @SecondFeature"
```

Comment: `-Dcucumber.options="--tags '@FirstFeature or @SecondFeature'"`

Comment: Thanks. I get "IllegalArgumentException: Not a file or directory: C:\Users\myUser\IdeaProjects\Poc\SecondFeature"

Comment: U can try  mentioning the path of the feature files like this `mvn test -Dcucumber.options="src/test/resources/first.feature src/test/resources/second.feature"`

Comment: Actually I defined the same tag for each of the feature files and it is sufficient for me for now. Thanks.

Comment: You can run all feature files in a directory by right-clicking and selecting `Run All Features in...` action.